# How does the Warhorse compares with other horses in Red Dead Redemption?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

When I purchased my copy of Red Dead Redemption, it came with a code that allowed me to get a deed for a unique horse...the "Warhorse".  How does it compare with the other horses in the game, specifically the better ones such as the Hungarian Half-Bred, etc?

Comment: How do you get the warhorse?

Comment: It's a freebie that you can get by buying the game through certain chains.  I believe I got the Warhorse by buying the game from Best Buy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing to the better horses only, it beats the Kentucky Saddler in nearly all aspects (can't confirm speed). However, in terms of stamina the Hungarian Half-Bred wins and in terms of speed the American Standardbred wins. So overall a great horse but NOT hands down the best for you, try the other top horses to see if they fit your play-style better.

For reference: http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/War_Horse, wikis are great for this kind of info in case you didn't already check.

Answer (score 1):

The Warhorse is THE best horse in the game.

The other 'best' horses such as:

- Hungarian Half-bred
- American Standardbred
- Kentucky Saddler

...share good speed ratios with good health ratios.

However, the Warhorse has the best speed ratio and the best health ratio. Period!

Comment: This sounds good...but how do you know?

Answer (score 1):

War horses do not scare. Unlike the rest who will kick you off when scared war horse will stick with till the bitter end.

Comment: That seems helpful. Do you have a source for this?